# ErrorException Undefined variable: test (View: F:\mca\SEM2\laravel\Example-app\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: function, testing, return, public

```
    public function show(){
        $test = "Test Views";
        return view('home',$test);
    }
```

in home.blade.php:

```
<h1>{{$test}}</h1>
```

Error Exception :

```
$test is undefined
```

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your public function is being declared outside a class.

This code seems to work:

```
function show(){
  $test = "Test Views";
  return view('home',$test);
}
```